# Python - Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use python to do a small machine learning example where I am plotting few coordinates and then predict the location as below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn import svm

x = [1, 5, 2, 8, 3, 9]
y = [2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 11]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()

X = np.array([[1,2],[5,8],[2,3],[8,8],[3,4],[9,11]])
print(X)

y = [0,1,0,1,0,1]

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 1.0)
clf.fit(X,y)

print(clf.predict([10,10]))
```

When I run it get this error:

```
C:\anaconda\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:395: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
```

I am new to machine learning and having difficulty in moving from here.

Comment: besides from the deprecation warning is the code not working? The warning  is just letting you know that a 1d array will not work in future versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting an error, it's a warning. The prediction will still be printed right after the warning message.

The solution is listed in the warning as well:

> Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a
>   single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Which gets rid of the warning as promised:

```
>> print(clf.predict(np.array([10,10]).reshape(1,-1)))
[1]
```

Comment: Thank you. works nowYes it shows there but i was trying to reshape the array as X = X.reshape(-1,1) which did not work. Now after doing the reshape while predicting it works.